# Dojo send Form to php-file then get the response in a div tag

Tags: dojo

hallo,
i would like to try a simple xmlhttprequest example to post a form to a php-file, the php-file reads the elemsnts value then give it back to a div tag, it works with a tradional code, but not with dojo, a get an error (firebug) thant sent is aborted, so this ist the content of [test.html](http://gist.github.com/551650)
content of test.php: echo $_POST['text'];
thank you.

Comment: now i think why, i try the same example but with dojo-release-1.4.3 and it works, under dojo-release-1.5.0 i get an error, unable to load test.php, status 0. i think it mieght be a bug, there is no posting at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue but only in one of my forms.

I suspect it is because of the vast amount of data submitted and it times out before the response.

So, to make sure it waits for the callback, I've added:

```
 sync: true
```

That seems to do it.